# Replace Tomcat StandardContext in server.xml

Tags: java, tomcat6

I'm running a Java application on Tomcat 6.0.24 that needs to be able to dynamically change the PATH for the JSESSIONID cookie at runtime. I spent a long time trying to manipulate the cookies in a filter, before deciding that the simplest approach might be to extend org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext and override the getEncodedPath function instead.

I have created a custom context called MultiTabContext that extends StandardContext and removed all the classpath issues that arose. I have defined my Context in catalina/conf/server.xml (I know it should be in context.xml, but I'll tackle that issue later):

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  ...
  <Service name="Catalina">
    ...
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      ...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        ...
        <!-- HERE IS MY CONTEXT -->
        <Context className="foo.app.server.MultiTabContext"
                 path=""
                 crossContext="false"
                 debug="0"
                 reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Here is my MultiTabContext:

```
package foo.app.server;

import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;

public class MultiTabContext extends StandardContext {

    @Override
    public String getEncodedPath() {
        return super.getEncodedPath();
    }
}
```

Because the path is "" I expected my context to be used on every request, instead of StandardContext. However, the application is still using the StandardContext, instead of mine. Anybody, have an idea how to define the Context, so that Tomcat uses mine instead of StandardContext (or know a better approach to dynamically changing the JSESSIONID cookie path)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure weather this will help to answer your question or not. But, I have an approach that might be helpful.
You can change JSESSIONID cookie path at runtime when the request is getting served.

```
/**
 * This gets the information from the request
 * 
 * @param parameter, pass JSESSION ID 
 * @return
 */
protected String getRequestInfo(HttpServletRequest request, String parameter)
{
    Cookie[] cookies = null;
    if (request.getRequestURI() == null || request.getRequestURI().length() == 0) 
    {
        performanceLogger.debug(" Request generated null pointer");
    }
    try 
    {
        cookies = request.getCookies();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cookies = null;

    }
    if (cookies == null || cookies.length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String paramValue = null;
    for (Cookie c : cookies)
    {
        if (c.getName().equals(parameter)) 
        {
            //change the path of JESSION ID over here 
            break;
        }
    }
    return paramValue;
}
```

Comment: That looks similar to what I was trying to do in the Filter. I would iterate over the cookies on the Request and update the path of the JSESSIONID. However, on the request where the JSESSIONID cookie is set, the internal workings of org.apache.cataline.connector.Request write directly to the response and do not update the Cookie[] array on the request. It's not until the next request that the JSESSIONID cookie will be available on the request, so you end up with two JSESSIONIDs, one with the original path, and one with the desired path.